# How to add SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN user=#{username} THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) PERCENT * FROM (SELECT .... )?

Tags: mysql, sql, h2, mybatis

My goal is to return either all of the row or just an empty array `[]` if "not one row" have column `user` with value `#{username}`.

This is the SQL SELECT statement

```
  @Select("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT user_detail.user, user_detail.name, channel_member.role " +
          "FROM user_detail " +
          "JOIN channel_member ON user_detail.user=channel_member.user " +
          "AND channel_member.uuid=#{channelUuid} )")
  List<MemberModel> getChannelDetail(String username, String channelUuid);
```

My goal is to change the 100 PERCENT to 0 PERCENT if "not one row" have column `user` with value of `#{username}`

What I've tried

1. Add `SELECT TOP (CASE WHEN user=#{username} THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) PERCENT ...`

```
  @Select("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT user_detail.user, user_detail.name, channel_member.role " +
          "FROM user_detail " +
          "JOIN channel_member ON user_detail.user=channel_member.user " +
          "AND channel_member.uuid=#{channelUuid} ) " +
          "LIMIT CASE WHEN user=#{username} THEN ALL ELSE 0 END")
  List<MemberModel> getChannelDetail(String username, String channelUuid);
```

But it throws an error

```
Column "USER" not found; SQL statement:
```

Comment: Can you check your TAGS please. TOP is not a MySQL syntax

Comment: @RiggsFolly My bad, I use H2 for test, I do use MySQL. I thought TOP is SQL generic. I will try to use `LIMIT` then.